# How to make program use virtual memory?

Tags: windows, perl, virtual-memory

How can I make a program use **virtual memory** in `Windows`?

I have a long `perl` script which is using *6GB+* of memory and increasing. My machine only has *8GB* or RAM. It is probably caused by a memory leak in a module, but there is nothing I can do about that now.

Is it possible to make it use virtual memory, or is this something controlled by `Windows` only?

Comment: Keep in mind that a 32-bit program is limited to using 2 or 3 GB, no matter how much memory you have. You'll probably need a 64-bit build of Perl (`x64` in the output of `perl -V:archname`) to get to the point where you use virtual memory. It will happen automatically as memory is needed.

Comment: @ikegami This is definitely 64-bit `perl`.  It is currently sitting at *7.17GB* used RAM out of *8GB*.  I would have thought it should swap to virtual memory before this point.

Comment: Obviously, physical memory is better for everything than virtual memory. Doesn't slow down disk IO or the processes using it; it's a win-win. Why would the operating system use virtual memory when it can use physical and move it as needed?

Answer (score 6):

The OS will provide virtual memory automatically if needed and if it's configured to have swap space.  You cannot control that from a Perl program.

If your Perl program has a memory leak eventually it will start being swapped to the page file.  When its memory consumption causes total memory to exceed the sum of your physical RAM plus page file, things will slow to a crawl and processes may become unresponsive and/or crash.

In any case, the size of the page file cannot be change dynamically, a reboot is required.  The only long-term fix is to find and fix the leak.

Comment: I have let the program run and it gets very close to the physical memory limit of my machine.  I would like it to swap to the page-file much earlier so it doesn't disrupt the performance of the rest of the system.  By the way, the memory leak is likely to be in an imported module.  It would take too long for me to find it.

Comment: Windows will swap when it needs to.  As soon as total committed memory becomes larger than physical RAM performance will drop, especially if there's a lot going on in other processes.  This is unavoidable.

Comment: @CJ7, it doesn't slow anything down just to be near the limit of your RAM. And if it needs more, then it will put unused blocks of your Perl RAM into VM and since leaked blocks are unused, you should see little slowdown.

Comment: @oldtechaa Yes it does slow down near the RAM limit. I have noticed a degradation of performance when there is less than 1GB free.

Comment: That is likely because it is starting to use virtual memory.  Even if it were possible, making it use virtual memory sooner would probably just make performance degrade sooner.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a shortcut of program that u want to run in virtual ram.
2. Right click on shortcut and click properties.
3. In properties, locate for target.
4. Copy and this at the end of target( --profile-directory="Profile 1"--disk-cache-dir=C:\ ).
5. Restart your pc.